# How to read a word 2003 document without COM in csharp?

Tags: c#, word-2003

Hey all, I need to read many word docs in server.
But you know,the component in .net is based on COM,it would work reliably if I use it.
It is so sick.You know, in word 2007,because of the xml file,there are many ways to read.
I wanna find a open source way to read word 2003,Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to read? Just the plain text of the main story? Meta data? Is formatting relevant?

Comment: You don't say what the problem really is, you don't outline what you're trying to do. You don't say what you want to read from the doc. I'd "open" a Word file with an unzipper and an XML viewer, but that's probably not that helpful for you. Very "subjective and argumentative", I'll probably vote to close.

Comment: You might want to also specify why exactly doesn't the COM component work for you.

Comment: @Franci - you need to have Office (or the PIA's) licensed and installed for all the clients. If it's a web application, Office is not supported as an installation on a server, with the exception of term serv. So, there is definitely a strong need for this.

Comment: @Роб Седер - yeah, I know this. However, it's not clear if this is what's preventing the OP from using COM.

Comment: I wanna read text from a word file only,and there are many files to read at one time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use the NPOI library to read .doc files: http://npoi.codeplex.com/

The library is the .NET version of the POI Java project and licensed under the Apache License.